# how to write/modify a xml file in SharePoint using a client side language(JavaScript)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml, sharepoint

Currently I'am working on a ASP.NET project and I have written a C# code to write/modify my XML document, which I'am using to structure my portal. 
  I now have to migrate my project to SharePoint, where I'am able to read my xml document but i don't know how to modify the same. Is there any way i can do it with the help of JavaScript.?
I have read many blogs, but wasn't able to get any satisfactory solution. My colleague told me that he modified a database using SharePoint using JavaScript so there would be a way to do the same with XML.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you modifying, and what is it that you can't do? Give details about your specific problem.

Comment: JavaScript **can not** modify anything on the server by itself. At some point, you'll still have to call some server side method which will modify the file.

Comment: @nunespascal --  I want to modify xml file(delete and add some new nodes). I am able to read the xml file using AJAX but i can't write it with AJAX.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici -- Is there any JavaScript Library that provides direct funtions to modify the xml structure by calling the server side methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [SharePoint JavaScript object model](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/09/04/using-the-javascript-object-model-jsom-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx).
This is a sharepoint library that allows you to manipulate sharepoint objects using javascript.

SharePoint does allow you to share documents too, so you could upload an xml document to a SharePoint library. But if you are building a SharePoint site, there are probably a lot better methods to customize it, like a SharePoint list, than using  an xml file in a SharePoint document library.